# How to make multi-threading process different task

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
import threading
import requests

with open("student.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r ]
    groups = {}

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['ref_num'])):
        items = []
        for i in g:

            chart_of_account = {k: v for k, v in i.items() if k in ['name', 'code']}
            item = {k: v for k, v in i.items() if k in ['debit', 'credit', 'desc','payee_id']}
            item.update({'chart_of_account': chart_of_account})
            items.append(item)
        groups.update({
            "date": i['date'],
            "desc": i['desc'],
            "ref_num": k,
            "items": items
        })

        def postRequest():
            postapi = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, json=groups, headers=headers)

        threads = []
        for i in range(3):
            t = threading.Thread(target=postRequest, args=())
            threads.append(t)

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            for i in threads:
                t.setDaemon(True)
                i.start()
                # keep thread
            for i in threads:
                i.join()
```

So far I could be posting the request with multi-thread example 3 threads. However, these 3 threads will post the same row data instead of post dirrent row of data.

CSV
date,ref_num,desc,debit,credit,payee_id,code,name

```
2019-01-31,L00001,john,30.00,,150,500,johnkino
2019-01-31,L00001,john,,30.00,150,600,johnkino
2019-01-31,L00002,john,30.00,,150,500,johnkino
2019-01-31,L00002,john,,30.00,150,600,johnkino
```

johnkino

Comment: You should include relevant `import` statements. I can tell one would be `csv`, but even after `import csv` your code still errors with `NameError: name 'groupby' is not defined`. Also you don't supply your `postRequest()` function. I suggest you review [how to make a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Reedinationer `postRequest()` seems to be defined inside the for loop as a nested function...

Comment: @kino.jom are you sure about the indentation of your code? Is it correct that `if __name__ == '__main__':` is inside the for loop? It is not forbidden, it is just very unusual...

Comment: @Ralf Ah yes you are correct. I'm not sure why OP would want to generate a function within a loop though...seems very inefficient. Also, they have a `for i in range(3)` nested inside `for i in g` using the same variable `i`

Comment: @Reedinationer I did imported the csv library and others library too.I just didn't post here.

Comment: @Ralf I'm not sure it correct or not but this code is working fine.

Comment: @kino.jom That is my point. In order for your script to be runnable on **my machine as well as anybody else's on this site** we need you to include all relevant code. If you copy/paste your post into a **blank and empty** python script (like we have to do) you will find it **does not** work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your goal with this project is, but to open and read a csv file and pass the information to threads would look something like this:

## test.csv

```
Hello
Kino
Jane
```

## workspace.py

```
import csv # posting my imports because the program doesn't run otherwise
import threading

groups = []
threads = []

with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    my_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in my_reader:
        groups.append(row)

# we no longer need to be nested within "with open()" because we loaded information into memory

def worker_thread(information):
    print(information[0]) # just print the first item from list (there is only 1)

for name in groups:
    # we pass information to thread with the 'args' argument
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker_thread, args=[name]) 
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join() # make sure that each thread is done printing before we end our program
```

Output:

```
Hello
Kino
Jane
```

## update

I'm not sure how you plan on generating URL's from your csv data, but the general structure should look like:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
import threading
import requests
from queue import Queue


def postRequest():
    print('thread starting')
    while True:
        item_to_process = q.get()
        print(item_to_process)
        q.task_done()
    # postapi = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, json=groups, headers=headers)


q = Queue()
with open("test.csv", "r") as csv_ledger:
    r = csv.DictReader(csv_ledger)
    data = [dict(d) for d in r]
    groups = {}

    for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['ref_num'])):
        items = []
        for i in g:
            chart_of_account = {k: v for k, v in i.items() if k in ['name', 'code']}
            item = {k: v for k, v in i.items() if k in ['debit', 'credit', 'desc', 'payee_id']}
            item.update({'chart_of_account': chart_of_account})
            items.append(item)
            groups.update({
                "date": i['date'],
                "desc": i['desc'],
                "ref_num": k,
                "items": items
                })

        for item in items:
            q.put(item)

for i in range(3):
    t = threading.Thread(target=postRequest)
    t.start()

print('Main thread waiting')
q.join()
print('Done.')
```

Which outputs:

```
thread starting
{'credit': '', 'payee_id': '150', 'chart_of_account': {'name': 'johnkino', 'code': '500'}, 'desc': 'john', 'debit': '30.00'}
thread starting
{'credit': '30.00', 'payee_id': '150', 'chart_of_account': {'name': 'johnkino', 'code': '600'}, 'desc': 'john', 'debit': ''}
{'credit': '', 'payee_id': '150', 'chart_of_account': {'name': 'johnkino', 'code': '500'}, 'desc': 'john', 'debit': '30.00'}
{'credit': '30.00', 'payee_id': '150', 'chart_of_account': {'name': 'johnkino', 'code': '600'}, 'desc': 'john', 'debit': ''}
thread starting
Main thread waiting
Done.
```

You can see in this case 3 threads is too many, and by the time the third starts all the data has been processed. That may change though as you implement more complicated procedures within the thread. Essentially you would change `'test.csv'` back to your csv's name, and then change `print(item_to_process)` into something that actually uses the data. I think this illustrates how to create a `Queue()` and put all your info into it, and then have your threads just keep unloading the queue until all your data has been processed.

Comment: I updated my code, the thread will always process the csv last row only without loop. That's why I keep the function inside my first loop in order to get all data from csv.

Comment: @kino.jom Your edit still does not work. I get `KeyError: 'ref_num'` on the line `for k, g in groupby(data, lambda r: (r['ref_num'])):`. Your csv file is obviously more than just 3 names on separate lines like mine is (From copy/pasting your second code block)

Comment: I give the sample csv as above

Comment: The data structure is not complete If use `q.put(item)`.However, thx your answer.